# Client of hostapd could not ping gateway

Tags: iptables, nat, hostapd

I have a laptop with Intel 8260 wireless module. And I ran following commands to make it a wireless router. Now the testing client can connect to my SSID, and get a DHCP address, both verified from hostapd/dnsmasq logs. But it cannot connect to anywhere, nor ping the gateway (10.10.100.1). Please help. Where should I check?

```
iw dev wlp2s0 interface add wlan0_sta type managed addr 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
iw dev wlp2s0 interface add wlan0_ap type managed addr 34:56:78:9a:bc:de
ip link set wlp2s0 down

ip link set wlan0_sta up
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0_sta -c Magicloud.conf
dhclient wlan0_sta

hostapd -B hostapd.conf
ip a add 10.10.100.1 dev wlan0_ap
dnsmasq -C dnsmasq.conf

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0_sta -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0_sta -o wlan0_ap -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0_ap -o wlan0_sta -j ACCEPT
```

**dnsmasq.conf**

```
bind-interfaces
dhcp-range=10.10.100.10,10.10.100.100,255.255.255.0,12h
interface=wlan0_ap
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
```

**hostapd.conf**

```
auth_algs=1
channel=11
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=g
interface=wlan0_ap
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
ssid=myssid
utf8_ssid=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypassword
```

Comment: Which gateway is the client trying to ping? (You have two.) The laptop running hostapd (10.10.100.1), or the upstream router that this laptop itself uses?

Comment: @grawity Hi, I have updated the question. By gateway, I meant 10.10.100.1.